# SQLite Database Download From URl for Android

Tags: android, sqlite, download

how can I download sqlite database from url for android? I have big one database. 
For Example;
Someone first time open the app. Then my db file download from url to assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not download a file in asset folder because this folder is bundled with the apk. That means its read only.
**So you have two option in hand:**

- use getCacheDir() (on internal memory) or getExternalCacheDir() (on
  SD card ) to download and retrieve your files.
- Add your db file in asset folder before making the apk.

Comment: I understand. Already I did second option. Well how can I do first option?

Comment: File dbfile = new File("/sdcard/Your_db_File.db" );  // Location where you saved your db from server
SQLiteDatabase  db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);